# Connection/Voltage-Detection/Voltage and Current Regulation

Tags: hardware

I'm using a Raspberry Pi zero for a drone. The Pi will be powered by a 11.1V battery. To reduce the voltage and current going into the Pi I'm thinking of using a [buck boost converter.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XFL78Q6)
If I use this converter, will it be compatible? And for voltage and battery percentage detection purposes, do I also use a voltage testing measurement unit or will the buck boost converter be good enough?

Answer (score 3):

To step down the battery voltage, you need a [buck converter.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) Adding the "boost" feature reduces efficiency, adds cost & complexity with no benefit.

The converter you've found on that website is unfortunately typical of the trash they push on the gullible - it has "disappointment" written all over it. The seller's description is [gibberish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibberish). At one point, they even admit:

> but the voltage and current meter values ​​are not accurate;

Their "Product Description" is a parody on Chinese goods - rife with illiteracy and incoherent claims. Here's how it looks today:

[image]

All of that said - the concept of using a dc-dc converter to maintain a regulated voltage from batteries is very sound - in fact, it's the *only* way to go really. But a sound idea executed poorly is not going to be a positive experience for you. FWIW, there are vendors in the world that are competent and honest. You might find something useful in [this collection of buck converters](https://www.pololu.com/category/192/d24v22fx-step-down-voltage-regulators).

Comment: My only concern is finding a buck converter/voltage regulator that can be programmed so it can show its reading on the computer/mobile screen remotely. Are the ones you posted programable?

Comment: I don't know - you could ask the vendor. If not, there are many electronics mfrs (think TI, Analog Devices, etc) that make hardware specifically for ***managing batteries***. Try searching for a "coulomb counter".